# How to tell if exists a linear map that satisfies these conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to do this exercise but I'm stuck on a).

For b) I have done it in two ways, first one obtaining the matrix of T supposing T is a linear map and I obtain T(0,1) and T(1,0) using the other cases and then when trying to obtain T(-3,2) using the matrix I end up in a contradiction.

The other way I did it was by seeing that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=-\alpha_3$ so if it was a linear map $T(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=T(-\alpha_3) \implies T(\alpha_1)+T(\alpha_2)=-T(\alpha_3)$ and this does not hold.

Any ideas on how to do exercise a)? Thanks in regards to everyone:)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since $(1,-1,1)$ is not a scalar multiple of $(1,1,1)$, they are linearly independent. 
You can extend it to a basis (by adding e.g. $(1,0,0)$), then assigning any values for them uniquely extends to a linear map.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a vector $v\in\Bbb R^3$ such that the set $\{(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),v\}$ is linearly independent (take $v=(1,0,0)$, for instance, a consider the only linear map from $\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R^2$ such that $T(1,-1,1)=(1,0)$, $T(1,1,1)=(0,1)$, and $T(v)=(0,0)$, for instance.

Comment: Could you confirm me if this is okay? I supposed that T(1,0,0)=(0,0) so I can form the basis {(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,0)} and with this I can form the matrix (1 0 0 \ 0 1 0) (the \ is a line change), and then solving T(1,-1,1) with that matrix I obtain (1,-1) which is not equal to (1,0) then we have a contradiction and done? Thank you José, obrigado:)

Comment: It's *much* simpler than that. It's simply that, when we have a basis $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of a vector space $V$ and $n$ vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ from a vector space $W$, then there is one and only one linear map $T\colon V\longrightarrow W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. No nedd to talk about matrices. Besides, I don't understand your reference to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The vectors $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are linearly independent, hence you can add a third vector to form a basis of $\:\mathbf R^3$.